# css - unexpected linebreak in <li> with elements display:flex in Internet Explorer (and Edge)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Internet Explorer (11) and Edge. Maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Following simple html and css is given:

```css
ul {
  background: green;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
      <div>bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
      <div>bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mqLykvs8/3/

In Internet Explorer and Edge there is a linebreak before "foo" which i do not expect and not showing up in any other browser.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of issues with IE and flex. I've made a solution that use another method of aligning `div` next to each other to solve your problem.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <div>foo</div>
      <div>bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <div>foo</div>
      <div>bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  background:green;
}

li {
  background:yellow; 
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

This solution uses `display: inline-block` to allow the `div` element to be next to each other and define the width of the element to the minimum before it pushes the div on the next row.

Comment: This did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set position for DIV like below (**Work only for IE and MS Edge**).

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  background:green;
}

li {
 background:yellow; 

}

div {
  display:flex;
  background:red;
  width:50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="position:absolute;">
      <div style="position:relative;">foo</div>
      <div style="position:relative;">bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="position:absolute;">
      <div style="position:relative;">foo</div>
      <div style="position:relative;">bar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE and Edge:

[image]

Note: This example is to correct the issue for IE and MS Edge. If you run this example in other browsers than it may give you inconsistent results.